# How to change background color of a selected ItemList Material-Ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have created a selectable component using Material-UI

```
let SelectableInfiniteList = makeSelectable(Infinite);
```

and put ListItem inside, now I want to change the default grayish color of a selected item, but I don't know how, if I give it a className

```
<ListItem className="list-item" primaryText={i}/>
```

and use list-item:focus selector I can change the background color as long as it is focused (but if I click somewhere else in the app) the focus is lost and the gray color shows up on the (still) selected item,

is there a way to change the selected item background color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Higher Order Component add new property `selectedItemStyle`!

```
<ComposedComponent selectedItemStyle={selectedItemStyle} value={this.state.selectedIndex} onChange={this.handleRequestChange} containerHeight={this.props.containerHeight} elementHeight={40}>
   {this.props.children}
</ComposedComponent>
```

Where `selectedItemStyle` is:

```
const selectedItemStyle = {
 backgroundColor: 'red'
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I had to use Global Theme override: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#global-theme-override

```
const muiTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiListItem: {
      root: {
        "&$selected": {
          backgroundColor: "red",
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: "orange",
          },
        },
      },
      button: {
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: "yellow",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This worked for me using `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3"`. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Change default selected gray color by passing `selected` style like this.

```
<ListItem
        button
        selected={true}
        classes={{ selected: classes.active }}>
  <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
</ListItem>
```

Style object should be like this.

```
active: {
  backgroundColor: "red"
}
```

Comment: For me, this is overwritten by `.MuiListItem-root.Mui-selected`.

Answer (score 7):

If you're interested in an approach without overriding styles globally,

```
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '&$selected': {
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      }
    },
  },
  selected: {},
});

const CustomSelectedListItem = (
  <ListItem
    button
    classes={{ root: classes.root, selected: classes.selected }}
    selected
  >
    <ListItemText primary="List Item" />
  </ListItem>
);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-brahmagupta-wkq8z). Material-UI [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet).

Answer (score 5):

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiListItem: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: 'blue',

          '&.Mui-selected': {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer local custom style, you can override `material-ui`'s component styles by `classes` (https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-classes)

- Check the `ListItem`'s CSS section at https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/#css and we know

```
...
selected    .Mui-selected   Pseudo-class applied to the root element if selected={true}.
...

The rule name we would override is: selected
```

- Create your custom styles like you want

```
// For example
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  listItemSelected: {
    color: 'red',
  },
}));
```

- Override `ListItem`'s `classes`

```
// Override rule "selected" by "listItemSelected"
<ListItem classes={{selected: listItemSelected}}>
  <ListItemText primary={"Hi"} />
</ListItem>
```

If you want to override global styles for it, please follow:

- https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#overriding-styles-with-global-class-names
- https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#css

Answer (score 2):

Using Material UI v4 and this worked for me:

```js
<ListItem button classes={{ root: classes.listItemRoot }}>
  ...
</ListItem>
```

with:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  listItemRoot: {
    "&.Mui-selected": {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
    }
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Work best when you used styled-components:

```
    const CustomListItem = styled(ListItem)`
         &&.Mui-selected {
           background-color: grey;
         }
    `

Use the the component in your code:
<CustomListItem>
...
</CustomListItem>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping I could find, unfortunately I was hoping not to have to use the string value `.Mui-selected`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the CSS rules of the TablePagination component(Material UI v3.9.4):

```
  menuItem:{
    "&[class*='MuiMenuItem-selected-']":{
      backgroundColor: "red !important",
    },
  },
```